# ROSserial has its own serial packet format, How to write a node that supports RS-232 packet format (basic serial packet) to communicate via USB port?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ros serial has its own serial packet format; I think, that does not supports the RS-232 packet format.
This is the reason that on every embedded hardware we need to install a rosserial_client program (a program compiled in hex code for specific target).

I have a robot base already designed using PIC microcontroller and can be controlled by sending command to the USB port means simply sending the serial data in ASCII code on USB port.

Please suggest me to write a node. Or if some one can share a sample node for the same it will be a learning platform.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70876/rosserial-has-its-own-serial-packet-format,-how-to-write-a-node-that-supports-rs-232-packet-format-(basic-serial-packet)-to-communicate-via-usb-port?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just look nodes of [iRobot](http://isr-uc-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/roomba_robot/trunk/roomba_500_series/src/)
or [mine](https://github.com/RoboCraft/robot_4wd/blob/master/ros_4wd_driver/src/robot_4wd_node.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-08-02**:
Please help me a little to understand the header file used, means how we can include these header in a xyz.cpp node, I earlier created a package with dependencies std_msgs rospy roscpp and serial packages ....... but I was unable to include header unix.h specified in serial package . pls help

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2013-08-02**:
#include "filename.h"

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-08-02**:
I tried that too, I wish you give more insight. Will be thankful.

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2013-08-02**:
maybe you should write in the CMake way to your package include directory or where you put this header file